# how to structure classes i an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to make an application, user have to put a fly number and click ok. I get this fly and contact a RESTful web service ( http://www.webserviceadress.com:8080/getStatut/The fly number that user put) get the JSON result parse it and put the result in a table View.

What are the classes that I should make? Should I use delegate?

I am thinking to create a class Stauts with the .xib and the attribute flyNumber .a class with the xib of the table view and the method who will put the result in the table view . And a class who will contact the webservice and parse JSON. And this class should delegate the class status.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You question has a million answers, but as an example you can try to architect your network code into tasks or operations.  For example, if you had an operation on service that was for submitting numbers, you can create a `SubmitNumberOperation` or `SubmitNumberTask` that perhaps takes in an NSDictionary of key/value pairs that will be the parameters given to the service.  Invoke the network call and then you can have the handler call some `parseResult` method that takes in the server's json response.  The idea would be to have a base class `NetworkOperation` that does all the network request launching for you that way you can have it call `parseResult`.  This would allow you to override parseResult in your subclasses.